# Packed Image on Chrome Extension won't load on .append()

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension, load

I've an image packed with my extension that I'd like to add to a page by using content script. I have my menu.js file that appends everything correctly, but I can't seem to work it out with the packed image.

I've tried

```
var loader = chrome.extension.getURL("repo/loader.gif");
```

and also

```
var loader = "chrome-extension://" + chrome.runtime.id + "/repo/loader.gif"
```

as well for

```
var loader = "chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/repo/loader.gif";
```

and even

```
var loader = "chrome-extension://" + __MSG_@@extension_id__ + "/repo/loader.gif";
```

And this is the jQuery to append

```
$('body').append('<div id="gacHover1"><span>Content is loading</span><img src="' + loader + '" width="470" height="300"></div>');
```

What Am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look to `web_accessible_resources` in your `manifest` file and make sure that you allow the packed image that you're trying to use.

```
{
  ...
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "images/*.png",
    ...
  ],
  ...
}
```

Or instead of `"images/*.png"` name just the images you want,e.g `repo/loader.gif`.

Hope this

Comment: I've tried this path already, but didn't have the image on the manifest file. Thank you so much, it worked :)